# Are typedefs for primitive values equivalent in golang?

Tags: go

Given this code:

```
type Philosopher int
const (
    Epictetus Philosopher = iota
    Seneca
)

func Quote(who Philosopher) string {
    fmt.Println("t: ", reflect.TypeOf(who))
    switch who {
    case Epictetus:
        return "First say to yourself what you would be; 
                and do what you have to do"
    case Seneca:
        return "If a man knows not to which port he sails, 
                No wind is favorable"
    }
    return "nothing"
}
```

Calling `Quote(5)` will print `Foo.Philosopher` as the type for 5.
Why didn't the type checker complain since that is what a type safe enums are supposed to do i.e. limit the scope of values ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are not enums as you think of them. Type `Philosopher` is more or less an alias of an int. More or less, because it is a fundamentally distinct type, which can define its own methods.

The point of it is to provide semantic grouping of constants in a way that is clear to the programmer. Additionally, one gets the benefit of Go's type checker during compile time. But only to the degree that a value passed into a `func(Philosopher)` can not be implicitly interpreted as such. Passing a literal `5` as the parameter works, because constants like that in Go are inherently untyped. This will not work;

```
n := 5
Quote(n)  // Compile error -> int is not Philosopher
```

Reason being that `n` is defined as `int`. There exists no implicit conversion between type `int` and `Philosopher`. However, this will work:

```
n := 5
Quote(Philosopher(n))
```

Because the type cast is valid. Go does not care whether or not `5` is a valid and pre-defined `Philosopher` constant.

Comment: @canadadry from the spec "Converting a signed or unsigned integer value to a string type yields a string containing the UTF-8 representation of the integer." Since any type declaration maintains the same conversion rules as the type it aliases,  converting an int to a Name works the same as converting an int to a string. http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions

Answer (score 1):

Go doesn’t make any guarantees about valid values, except for those implied by int. The use of iota is just a convenience for defining a series of constants; it doesn’t say anything about valid values.

5 is a valid int, and therefore a valid Philosopher. You could also create const Plato = Philosopher(5).

Answer (score 1):

Shorter answer should be [like](https://tour.golang.org/basics/16) :

> An untyped constant takes the type needed by its context.